# 403 error request to magento 1.9 folders

Tags: php, magento-1.9, webhooks

I have magento connected with with a 3rd API, I receive a webhook notification response from the api but it cannot process any file and generate this **403 Forbidden** error regarding some access rights.
I've changed the magento folder to read and write access but the issue still the same.

```
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /magento1.9/app/code/local/Ns/Thorleif/Helper/Data.php
on this server.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the **.htaccess** in `\magento1.9\app` having the value **Deny from all**